# Command line for Dropbox connection in Duplicati backup

Tags: command-line, backup, dropbox, increment, duplicati

I'm trying to backup Folders from local drive to Dropbox using Duplicati command in Command prompt. (Backup should be Incremental)

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Office_Works\Duplicati\Duplicati 1.3.4\Duplicati>Duplicati.CommandLine.exe backup a https://www.dropbox.com/

Enter passphrase: **
Confirm passphrase: **
**Unable to find backend for: https://www.dropbox.com/**
```

"a" is my folder in local drive. Now I want to know how to make a connection with Dropbox using command lines. Is any particular way to connect Dropbox using duplicati commands?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for DropBox in Duplicati.

Others have reported using a local folder under the DropBox folder as a destination, such that the DropBox client synchronizes the folder for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project that can upload files to dropbox from the command prompt.  It's very lightweight and both installation and usage couldn't have been easier!

[PneumaticTube](https://github.com/hartez/PneumaticTube)

If you use it the first time it will open your browser to ask for permission to access your dropbox account but from then on it's easy sailing.